# Undefined variable $data

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-blade

error:
Undefined variable $data

```
@foreach ($data as $d)
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        <div class="bg-welcome3">
             <img src="{{ $d->image }}" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

my route:

```
Route::resource('welcome', WelcomeController::class);
```

```
WelcomeController:
public function index()
    {
        $data = Product::all();
        return view('welcome',compact('data'));
    }
```

I want to display data in view('welcome') but the data is undefine, even though the routes and controllers that I use are correct

Comment: Try to use dd() or echo() function to debug the $data variable and check the value of the $data variable in the controller, to make sure it's not empty or null.

Comment: I've done it on other pages and the results are successful, but the welcome view doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

try this instead Check and make sure that welcome.blade.php is present in inside [yourprojectname]\resources\views

Comment: This looks more like a comment than a solution!